Cypress tests failing with duplicate step name in separate test definition - Wrong step running
I have 2 similar tests within the same feature file. They are essentially the same test except one expects to find a list of data while the other expects no data.
They both share identical step names, however the implementations of the final step is different.
myfeature.feature
Scenario Outline: Log in and see data
    Given User visits page
    When User logs in
    Then Should see expected result // Same name step

Scenario Outline: Log in and no data
    Given User visits page
    When User logs in
    Then Should see expected result // Same name step

The test definition file looks something like:
describe('Log in and see data', () => {
    Given('User visits page', () => {
        // Do page visit
    });
    When('User logs in', () => {
        // Perform log in logic
    });
    Then('Should see expected result', () => {
        cy.get('my-component').should('be.visible');
    });
});

describe('Log in and no data', () => {
    Given('User visits page', () => {
        // Do page visit
    });
    When('User logs in', () => {
        // Perform log in logic
    });
    Then('Should see expected result', () => {
        cy.get('my-component').should('not.exist');
    });
});

When I am running Cypress it shows that the first test passes correctly, however the second test fails and when I look into the test run it seems that the Should see expected result step is hitting the Then definition from the top describe block for the other test...
Questions around the behaviour seen:

Is there any reason for this?
Is there a way in which I can stop this from happening and the test hit the correct definition?
What is the best practise here?


The subtext is you are expecting to match feature scenario title with describe() title.
But you can see from the basic example that step definitions do not use describe(). In fact, I'm surprised there is no error thrown.
# cypress/e2e/duckduckgo.feature
Feature: duckduckgo.com
  Scenario: visiting the frontpage
    When I visit duckduckgo.com
    Then I should see a search bar

// cypress/e2e/duckduckgo.ts
import { When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

When("I visit duckduckgo.com", () => {
  cy.visit("https://www.duckduckgo.com");
});

Then("I should see a search bar", () => {
  cy.get("input").should(
    "have.attr",
    "placeholder",
    "Search the web without being tracked"
  );
});

Once you grasp that, it's clear that the titles must be matched on keyword Then and the strings following (in feature file) and title for the Then() method. So the error becomes obvious - don't try to use the same title twice.
Besides, I think the readers of your test reports would thank you for using more explicit descriptions
Then('Should not show any data', () => {
  cy.get('my-component').should('not.exist');

Then('Should show the data', () => {
  cy.get('my-component').should('be.visible');


Thanks for the detailed explanation. I did think that this was the way, it's just that I've inherited a codebase with the formatting that I showed. Definitely not how I'd seen it done before, but was just wondering if I could get things working the way it was before trying to find the time and resource to get it done properly. And yes, I agree for the descriptive names being easier for all to read. Bloody contractors :-P
